# SSRS and SSAS data source error while connecting to oracle database

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, ssas

We have oracle database and we are developing SSAS cubes and SSRS reports based of that oracle database tables.
I am able to connect to Oracle Database thru SQL Developer and run queries in SQL Developer. so permissions wise I have all of them. But see below issues.
Issue 1.
I am trying to create a datasource in SSRS to connect to oracle database I am unable to Edit the connection string see below image
[image]

Issue 2.
This is while using creation a data source for Cube development I was able to successfully connect using on of the logon details we commonly use for the database connection.

[image]

But after going and making changes to a query in DIM table in cube and select OK then this below error is fired. so I am unable to make changes inside a cube table.
[image]

Issue 3: When I am trying to run the report in Report Server which is connected to oracle Database this is error I am getting.
[image]

I don't know if these issues are all related or different from each other. I tried searching online and didn't find exact solution for all the problems. 
Tools Used:
SQL Server Mgmt Studio 17.2
Visual Studio 2015 with SSDS 17.4 (latest version)
Oracle 11.2.0
All these software were running on Windows 10

Comment: It is hard to answer all your questions.  On Issue 1: I think you are using SSRS 2016 or 2017, I have noticed on pages when you first open them nothing is editable.  If you re-click the same page it then lets you edit things.  Also, for me, I have used ODBC connections to connect to Oracle.  Be sure to setup the ODBC on the SSRS Server and on your PC.

Comment: The very bottom error says your account is locked. Try unlocking it.

Comment: I tried changing the connection and then coming back oracle database but still didn't work. We have don't have ODBC setup. One of my team mate is using same connection which works fine. But not me.